# Как правильно подключить extension в php?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp

Подключил в PHP библиотеку `"extension = php_gmp.dll in php.ini"` для использования функции вычисления факториала.

Пробовал: в одно строке с `<?php` после `;` написать библиотеку, убрать `;`, но тогда появится ошибка

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "=" in ...(путь файла, который я проверял, и он верный)... on line 2";`
```

пробовал без `;` в одну строку после `<?php`, также в конце файла `php.ini` написал `extension = php_gmp.dll`, но не работает.

Ответ выносится, как `"Ответ: $Result"; //Ответ ?>"`. Что делать?

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <HTML lang= "ru">
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Цикл while </title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form name="7" action="2 (7).php" method ="POST">
            <label> Введите своё число: </label> <br/>
            <input type = "text" name= "Chislo"> <br/>
            <input type = "submit" name= "Gotovo" value= "Нажми"/>
            </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
    
    <HEAD>
```

Результат HTML:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PHP:

```
    <?php; 
    extension=php_gmp.dll in php.ini //Подключение библиотеки
    $Result = 0; 
    
        while (0 <= $_POST["Chislo"]) 
        {
            
            for ($Schot = 0; $Schot < $_POST["Chislo"]; $Schot++) 
            $Result = gmp_fact($Schot) / 5; //Деление суммы чисел
        }
        echo "<br/>Ответ: $Result"; //Ответ 
    
    ?>
```

Ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всмысле не в html коде? Дело как раз в нем. Вы не понимаете как выводить переменную. И код вставить нужно текстом!

Comment: Вы понимаете что такое текст и картинка? Разницу? Текст текстом!

Comment: Код необходимо вставлять текстом. По картинке цикл `while` выглядит бесконечным. Скорее всего проблема с выводом связана пробелом между переменной и `[`

Comment: обрати внимание, что в процессе смены картинки на код, поменялся сам код, и скорее всего, для него теперь не соответствует вывод

Comment: если полностью убрать цикл, оставить один вызов `echo` ошибка воспроизводится?

Comment: Да, воспроизведётся.

Comment: и в таком виде? `<?php $Result = 0; echo "Ответ: $Result"; ?>`

Comment: Я вставил код, где цикл while и for. Остался тот код , который Вы мне дали в последнем сообщении и ответ выдаёт постоянно ноль, если даже вести 20. В задание написано сверху, что нужно использовать цикл while.

Comment: @StackOverflow, если выдает `Ответ: 0` а не `Ответ: $Result"; ?>` значит проблема была в коде с циклами, которые ты удалил

Comment: @Grundy, код я не удалял. Проблема с подключением библиотеки, из-за этого ошибка.

Comment: у тебя в файле прям так написано? `extension=php_gmp.dll in php.ini //Подключение библиотеки`?

Comment: какая операционная система стоит?

Comment: У меня стоит ОС windows.

Comment: В файле, где я цикл написал, да. Я про : extension=php_gmp.dll in php.ini //Подключение библиотеки

Comment: попробуй оставить только `;extension=php_gmp.dll`. А сама дллка есть?

Comment: Я не знаю, о каком именно файле сейчас говорится, потому что здесь такого нет https://metanit.com/php/tutorial/1.2.php. В xampp автоматически загружается php.ini и не надо его переименовывать из  php.ini-development, хотя файл php.ini-development тоже есть.

Comment: Ты про php.ini? Когда ты сказал "попробуй оставить только ;extension=php_gmp.dll. А сама дллка есть?" ?

Comment: @StackOverflow, у тебя есть конкретная строчка кода. в комментарии речь про изменение конкретно этой строчки кода.

Comment: @StackOverflow, код по твоей ссылке на метанит так же отличается от того, что привел ты. Попробуй сделать именно так, как указано в примерах, не придумывая код от себя.